# How to manage non-file components?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

What is the best way to manage components whose contents can't be easily mapped to a keypath (ie file, directory or registry key) ?

Here are some of the installed entities I've dealt with over the years that had this problem:

- Database scripts
- Scheduled tasks
- CryptoAPI key pairs
- HTTP.SYS url reservations

Initial installation isn't a problem; nor is uninstallation. However, what about repair or upgrade scenarios? How does Windows Installer "know" that a component needs to be reinstalled/upgraded, if it can't be easily associated with a keypath?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go with a "proxy" path by creating a directory containing a dummy file for each of the items you listed?

Comment: Well that's what I've been doing. But if the user repairs the install and the proxy directories are there, I'm guessing the actions tied to those proxies won't be run, and therefore those items won't actually be repaired.